# Product of two Monte Carlo simulations

Tags: probability, distributions, monte-carlo

Would greatly appreciate any help on the math concept here.  I’m working in MS Excel, so if anyone can speak to that specifically, that would be an added bonus.

I have a Monte Carlo simulation to illustrate the likelihood of an event happening (let’s say winning on a slot machine).  I can make a histogram to show all the different frequencies of the event and their relative likelihoods.

Now, each time the event occurs, it pays some amount of money, which is also variable.  I have a second Monte Carlo simulation showing all the different possible payouts and their relative frequencies.

**Mathematically, how do I combine these two distributions into a single illustration of what a person might win on the slot machine?**

Say I run 1,000 simulations of frequency in Column A   (  =NORMINV(RAND(),mean,standard_dev)  )

And 1,000 simulations of the winnings in Column B.  I had figured I would just make a Column C which is frequency times winnings (Column A times Column B), and plot those 1,000 products on a histogram to show the overall expectation of winning in terms of dollars.  But I’m afraid that perhaps it shouldn’t be that simple….

Mathematically, is there a flaw in this logic?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I correctly followed what you're doing (some details would need to be clarified to be certain), this should be correct.

We could consider it as an application of the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation). Specifically, consider it in this form:

> ... if $\{ A_i \}_i$ is a finite or countable partition of the sample space, then
>   $${\displaystyle \operatorname {E} (X)=\sum _{i}{\operatorname {E} (X\mid A_{i})\operatorname {P} (A_{i})}.}$$

You wish to estimate the expected winnings by simulation, so you'd multiply expected winnings under each outcome ($E(X_i|A_i)$ by the proportion of times it occurs (estimating $A_i$).

The desired expectation would be the sum over all of those products.

Similarly, if the outcome given event $A_i$ in turn depends on still other events (denoting those in turn by variables $B$, $C$ etc), you could simulate over those events and replace the expectation with the value of the conditional outcome (which will again be a matter of using simulation to approximate the expectation; once your expectations are all fixed numbers, you can regard it as simply applying the definition of [expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Finite_case) under some countable set of outcomes).